# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '|' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input is a single row or multi-row table with 7 columns of information
I want to turn those 7 columns into a multi row table with the first column repeated and another two columns, the second with a componentID and the third column being the componentLength.

Here is the original question below.

```
  SELECT
        (CASE 
            WHEN SpecificationID = '889' AND RTTopEntryLength > '0' AND RTSideEntryLength > '0' 
               THEN CONVERT(varchar, (infill_id + '|' + infill_id + '|' + infill_id))
            WHEN SpecificationID = '889' AND RTTopEntryLength = '0' AND RTSideEntryLength > '0' 
               THEN CONVERT(varchar, (infill_id + '|' + infill_id))
            WHEN SpecificationID = '889' AND RTTopEntryLength > '0' AND RTSideEntryLength = '0' 
               THEN CONVERT(varchar, (infill_id + '|' + infill_id))
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar, infill_id) 
         END) AS 'InfillIDList'
    FROM 
        INFILLTABLE
    WHERE 
        SpecificationID = '889'
```

I get this error :

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '|' to data type int.
```

What am I missing here? I'm converting the whole string to Varchar, why is it having an error trying to convert to integer again?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to process this: (infill_id+'|'+infill_id), and getting an error.
You can realize the same result by: `select  3+'jj'+2`, you'll see the message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'jj' to data type int.

Change `(infill_id+'|'+infill_id)` to be `concat(infill_id,'|',infill_id)`

(And it tries to evaluate as an int *before* it will convert the result to varchar)

If you're really interested why you can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for the assist on the Concat function, it came in very handy on another query I was working on today.

Comment: I was getting confused between combining table column results in the select part of the query rather than combining the text of them into a longer string.